# vs2008: not honoring 'my documents' path setting

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

vs2008 (and earlier versions) always creates empty folders in `c:\users\<username>\my documents` every time it runs. Is there any way to get it to honor the location of 'my documents'? It's never on my c: drive. This leads to the annoying problem of 2 'my documents' folders in windows explorer.
MS is not following it's own guidelines. And there is a 'MyDocumentsLocation' value in the vs registry settings that is correct, but ignored.

Comment: On my system, it used the correct directory (F:) upon install under both XP and Vista, so you must be doing something out of the ordinary.

Comment: I moved my documents after I installed visual studio. Each time it runs, VS restores the folders to the original location of my documents. This is fixed using options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the Tools>Options dialog, Projects and Solutions tab.
This sets a number of locations that Visual Studio uses, and these usually default to MyDocuments.